# Highlighting a point in geom_jitter

Tags: ggplot2, scatter-plot, jitter

I have a data set with several species that shall be visualised via geom_jitter. In every species, there is one observation that I want to highlight as red point (i.e. this study). However, I couldn't find a useful explanation and hope anybody here can help to fix this.

The data have 7 variables and 65 observations.
The 7 variables are
Genus
Species
Energy
Organics
CN
CP
Reference

The variable "Reference" contains many different things, among others "this study".

The code looks like this:

``

```
ggplot(Genus,aes(x=Genus,y=Organics,colour=Genus))+
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.15),alpha=1,size=2)+
  labs(x="\nGenus",y="AFDW % DW\n")+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=18),
  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
  axis.title.y=element_text(size=18),
  legend.title=element_text(colour="black",size=14),
  legend.text=element_text(face="italic",colour="black",size=14),
  axis.text.y=element_text(size=14,colour="black"),
  axis.ticks=element_blank())
p23
```

``

Does anybody has an idea how to highlight the points belonging to "this study" in every species scatter plot?

Comment: Have you tried `geom_jitter(aes(colour = ifelse(Reference == "this study", Reference, Genus)))` ?

Comment: The restructuring didn't result in the wished highlighting of the value from the present study. The solution suggested by teunbrand didn't result in the wished plot. ``p<-ggplot(Genus,aes(x=Genus,y=Organics))+
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.15),alpha=1,size=3)+
  labs(x="\nGenus",y="AFDW % DW\n")+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=14,colour="black",angle=45,hjust=1,face="italic"),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=14,colour="black"),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())
p``

Answer (score 2):

Without any relevent example data I can't be more specific as to how to achieve this. Here is how you could achieve it on some dummy data, as mentioned in a comment:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Genus = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 50),
  Organics = rnorm(100),
  Reference = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Pick out 2 points in across groups to be highlighted
df$Reference[rpois(1, 20) + c(0, 50)] <- "This Study"

ggplot(df, aes(Genus, Organics)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.15),
              aes(colour = ifelse(Reference == "This Study", 
                                  "Highlight", "Don't Highlight"))) +
  labs(colour = "Highlight?")
```

[image]

You can choose the highlight colours by adding `+ scale_colour_manual(values = c("my_colour_1", "my_colour_2"))`

Comment: Wondeful, it finally work and I got the plot, I was looking for. Thank you very much for your assistane!